# Parsing out URLs in email messages

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue in some of my code, i cannot seem to think of the best way to do this, all i want to do is extract a URL from a pop3 email message depending on if the domain is in the "to check" array, for example if "stackoverflow.com" is in the email message, i would extract all urls in the message body that contains "stackoverflow.com" in it, and just perform a quick WebClient() request with that url.

Code:

```
    private void BgwEmails_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bool finished = false;
            Pop3Client pop3 = new Pop3Client();
            if (pop3.Connected)
            {
                pop3.Disconnect();
            }

            pop3.Connect(txtBoxMailServer.Text, int.Parse(txtBoxPort.Text), chkSSL.Checked);
            pop3.Authenticate(txtBoxUsername.Text, txtBoxPassword.Text, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

            int messageCount = pop3.GetMessageCount();
            if (messageCount == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Helpers.ReturnMessage("[ " + messageCount + " ] Message(s) in your inbox.");

            int count = 0;
            for (int d = 1; d <= messageCount; d++)
            {
                bgwEmails.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                if (bgwEmails.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    Helpers.ReturnMessage($"Cancelling link activator ...");
                    return;
                }
                if (finished)
                {
                    return;
                }

                OpenPop.Mime.Message message = null;
                message = pop3.GetMessage(d);
                if (null == message || null == message.MessagePart || null == message.MessagePart.MessageParts) {
                    continue;
                }

                string textFromMessage = null;
                try
                {
                    textFromMessage = message?.MessagePart?.MessageParts[0]?.GetBodyAsText();
                } catch (Exception) {
                    continue;
                }

                MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[0];

                if (null == messagePart || null == messagePart.BodyEncoding || null == messagePart.Body || null == messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body)) {
                    continue;
                }

                string linkToCheck;
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    linkToCheck = wc.DownloadString("https://www.thesite.com/api.php?getActivationLinks=1");
                }
                var linksToClickArray = linkToCheck.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                //Helpers.ReturnMessage(textFromMessage);

                for (var i = 0; i < linksToClickArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    var regex = new Regex(linksToClickArray[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    var matches = regex.Matches(textFromMessage);

                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            count++;
                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { listBoxEmailsClicked.Items.Add("Clicked: " + match.Value); }));
                            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                            {
                                Helpers.ReturnMessage(match.Value);
                                wc.DownloadString(match.Value);
                            }                              
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (null != textFromMessage)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { txtStatusMessages.AppendText(textFromMessage); }));
                }
            }
            Helpers.ReturnMessage($"Emails downloaded successfully! You clicked [ " + count + " ] activation links.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Helpers.ReturnMessage($"POP3 Error: " + ex.Message + ".");
        }
    }
```

I do a request here: **https://www.thesite.com/api.php?getActivationLinks=1** which contains a list of domains to check for in the messages, they just come back one line at a time like:

```
thesite1.com
thesite2.com
etc
```

The code works as far as connetcing and downloading, i just cannot seem to think of a way to parse of the urls only if it matches a domain in the target list, any help or advice would be appreciated.